# Angular expressions resolve differently than the console

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, expression

I have an expression that runs differently in javascript than in angular's {{expressions}}. Can anyone tell me why?

expression:

```
(parseInt("12px")*2).toString()+"px"
```

Evaluated in javascript, it resolves to `24px`.  In an angular expression, it's `NaNpx`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenkron/neuTA/1151/)

Comment: you should remove the 'px' from the first string, and just concatenate it in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{}}` tell Angular that in your view, you have an Expression to interpolate. Angular expressions do not support all of JavaScript. For documentation check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

If you need all of JavaScript. It is better to wrap the logic in a controller function.

> Excerpt from docs:
>
> It might be tempting to think of Angular view expressions as
>   JavaScript expressions, but that is not entirely correct, since
>   Angular does not use a JavaScript eval() to evaluate expressions. You
>   can think of Angular expressions as JavaScript expressions with
>   following differences:
>
> Attribute Evaluation: evaluation of all properties are against the
>   scope doing the evaluation, unlike in JavaScript where the expressions
>   are evaluated against the global window.
>
> Forgiving: expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null,
>   unlike in JavaScript, where trying to evaluate undefined properties
>   can generate ReferenceError or TypeError.
>
> No Control Flow Statements: you cannot do any of the following in
>   angular expression: conditionals, loops, or throw.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to parse a string to integer with alpha characters in it, I guess javascript removes the characters for you, whereas angular keeps it literal.

```
(parseInt("12")*2).toString() + "px";
```

Would be the correct angular syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `parseInt` function on `$scope` and it works.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.parseInt = parseInt;
  $scope.foo = function() {
    return (parseInt("12px") * 2).toString() + "px";
  }
});
```

With Angular Expressions, functions are fetched from `$scope` instead of the global namespace.

From the Docs:

> - **Context:** JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfx71gbq/)